# Retrieve only session clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have buttons which each of it holds session. User need to click one of the button, then in the next page user can view the data clicked by them. Here is my code behind:

```
public partial class Welcome_Proton : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carA"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carB"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carC"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carD"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carE"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carF"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carG"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
protected void Button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carH"] = Label1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
}
}
```

To retrieve back the session, I use this code in "BookingForm.aspx" code behind: `string car = Session["car"].ToString();`
The problem now is, what code should I write in order to retrieve back the session only click by user? How to retrieve only a session click by user? You may ask me if you not clear with my question. Many thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why it has to be different Session variables for each button?

Comment: you have a lot of repetition there

Comment: why do you need so many session variables to store the same value?

Comment: Maybe because I think different buttons, different session variables. Am I wrong?

Comment: why different session variables are used as you are setting the same value(Label1.Text) to each session,you can use the same session name to set and get the values...

Comment: @ stuck: the value you are storing in the session is same in all the cases. So wats the point in creating so many sessions. You are wrong!!

Comment: @ stuck: do this- create different labels with different text and with each click store different values in sessions. That makes some sense in using so many sessions.

Comment: @Stuck We're not sure why exactly you implemented it this way, but I'm pretty sure it can be done in some other, more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, a *quick and dirty* solution would be to also save the key into the `Session` like this:

```
protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["carG"] = Label1.Text;
    Session["buttonKey"] = "carG";
}
```

Once the `BookingForm.aspx` is loaded you can get the value from session using this code:

```
private string GetSessionValue()
{
    var key = Sesssion["buttonKey"] as string;
    return Session[key] as string;
}
```